# Using component with one props

Tags: vue.js

I am reading Vuejs [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) and I can say it is confusing. without running example or complete examples they have snippets, I am trying to understanding about using one prop instead of using a each for every property. I am trying to make a example from the docs but I cannot. Following is my code.

```
Vue.component('blog-post', {
    props:['post'],
    template:`
    <div class="blog-post">
    <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
  </div>  
    `
})
new Vue({
    el : '#app',
    data: {

    }
})
```

HTML

```
<div id="app">
        <blog-post
        v-for="post in posts"
        v-bind:key="post.id"
        v-bind:post="post"
      ></blog-post>
</div>
```

The error I am getting is "[Vue warn]: Property or method "posts" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render". I am confused on how one value can be used to show many objects.

Answer (score 0):

props:['post'] check this plural. I figure that you are passing an array of posts to the component, and inside that component iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

You need top pass data.

```
Vue.component('blog-post', {
    props:['post'],
    template:`
    <div class="blog-post">
    <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
  </div>  
    `
})
new Vue({
    el : '#app',
    data: {
        posts: [
            {
                title:  'post-1' 
            },
            {
                title:  'post-2' 
            },
            {
                title:  'post-2' 
            }   
        ]
    }
})
```

> so now

```
<blog-post
    v-for="post in posts"
    v-bind:key="post.id"
    v-bind:post="post"
></blog-post>
```

you can use `v-for` and it will take `posts` data and iterate through it and pass single `post` to the component and component will use that property and render html.

here when `blog-post` will receive `post` it will be this [ **v-bind:post="post"** ]

```
{
    title:  'post-1' 
}
```

and it will use its `post.title`

> v-for it will iterate this `blog-post` component [in our case 3 times] and pass each `post object` which is in array as `post` property of `blog-post` component.

if any doubts please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question but I'll try to help:

1. The reason you get the error is because you are looping posts, but you haven't defined them anywhere, so you need to change your main instance data:

   ```
   new Vue({
       el : '#app',
       data: {
          posts: [{author: "someone", text: "something", title: "Some post"}]
       }
   })
   ```
2. There is a shorthand for v-bind, so instead you can write:

   ```
   <div id="app">
           <blog-post
           v-for="post in posts"
           :key="post.id"
           :post="post"
         ></blog-post>
   </div>
   ```